# Switcher on Windows 10 taking screenshots automatically

Tags: windows-10

I'm using [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) on Windows 10.

I changed the default <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> to <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to see which is more comfortable(since those two aren't bound by Windows).

Problem is, whichever key binding I set, *I get a screenshot in my `%userhome%/pictures/screenshots directory` whenever I press the keys to go to Switcher view*, I tried right click on the tray icon and click `Switch`, this way I don't get a screenshot. I can't find anything related in the `settings`.
Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you have some other program or alias taking a snapshot of your screen.  Typically the print screen button or ALT + print screen is reserved for capturing a screen / window respectively.  I'd try turning off other programs until you find the culprit.  I tried your key combinations and nothing by default caught any screen captures.  I'm assuming some other program is doing this that you are unaware of.

Comment: I changed to ``ctrl+shift+alt+` `` and the problem's gone, and now ``win+` `` `win+w` `win+f` gives me a `beep`(means they're not bound to anything). So confusing. Maybe I'll just try to avoid the dark `win` key. :3

Comment: According to http://www.wikihow.com/Take-Screenshots-in-Windows-8 , `win+printscreen` will save a picture named `screenshot(123)` in the `screenshot` folder, which is exactly what I'm getting. So my guess is `win+*` bindings somehow triggers the function of `win+printscreen`, which is a minor bug when combining Switcher(written years ago) with Windows 8+.